# net.Read Problems during receiving

Tags: sockets, go, testing

I feel that there may be a problem when the receiving server returns. Relevant code follows:

```golang
const RecvBufferSize = 1024 * 64

for {
        readBuff := make([]byte, RecvBufferSize)
        n, err := udp_client.conn.Read(readBuff)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("socket recv error.", zap.String("errMsg", err.Error()))
            return
        }

        select {
        case udp_client.recvMessage <- readBuff[:n]:
        case <-udp_client.closeTest:
            log.Info("close recvFrom", zap.String("Stack", string(debug.Stack())))
            close(udp_client.recvMessage)
            return
        }
    }
```

Each time this code receives the information returned by the server, it will re apply for an address of []byte. Will this put pressure on the GC when the received data volume is compared? Is there any good solution?

[image]I'm using Go for performance testing.

Comment: Each loop iteration allocates a new buffer, so yes it will put *some* pressure on the GC. However, since the slice is shared outside this goroutine, that's probably the best approach anyway. Are you seeing a performance issue related to GC? Have you benchmarked/profiled your application?

Comment: First determine if it is actually a problem. If it is, then you could just pre-allocate a large slice, or maintain a free list of slices.

Comment: You can try use sync.Pool but you should measure if this is your real issue

Comment: I used statsview to generate monitoring during program operation. Only GC number does not seem normal, and the program will exit with an error after running for a period of time. Therefore, I asked whether it is related to GC.
I'm a novice. There may be some mistakes, I hope the mogul can correct me.

Comment: The statsview monitoring screenshot was re-edited and posted in the question